# Google Reader auto-mark read possible?

Tags: google, rss, google-reader, feeds

I'm using Google Reader, there is a function that allows us to mark all as read which is really good, but

I was wondering is there anyway to Mark the RSS as read automatically when they come in?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point of marking a feed read automatically. Why have it, then? That said, if you're using the default view, there is a setting for automarking read any item as you scroll past it. If that's not sufficient then, no, Google Reader doesn't currently allow you to automatically mark a feed as read as messages are pulled in.

Comment: @AlEverett well blogs like mashable give 50 items per day, so basically i usually only read the headings.

Comment: That's why I have it in list mode.

Comment: @AlEverett I don't understand you, what do you mean ?

Comment: I don't use the expanded view, just the list view, so that I can easily skim over the headings and select the items I want to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, it is not possible. Google Reader doesn't currently allow you to automatically mark a feed as read as messages are pulled in.